# GlassFish Server deploy Permission denied :connect, false

Tags: java, jsp, server, glassfish

[image: This is the error message I am getting as output. Please help me out with real solution!!!]

I have tried for every solution on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
But none of them worked with my system Windows 8.1 Netbeans 8.2 with jdk 8

Here are the log details!!! of Output of GlassFish Server. I have tried every normal solution but can't get into it, Please help me out with this! I have tried every setting with admin and password properties of server. Also edited build-impl.xml file by changing FALSE to TRUE in specified line. Also Netbeans is running in administrator mode. I have tried start:domain one method. Please tell me some effective method.

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Aug 09, 2018 11:00:17 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Aug 09, 2018 11:00:17 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Aug 09, 2018 11:00:17 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Aug 09, 2018 11:00:17 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@50fad361 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Asus\personal_domain\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (15,356ms), startup services(3,170ms), total(18,526ms)
Severe:   Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.Selectors.newSelector(Selectors.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.create(SelectorRunner.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOTransport.startSelectorRunners(NIOTransport.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOTransport.start(NIOTransport.java:506)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:185)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:121)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 31 more

Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@772861aa as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@55a88417.
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@772861aa from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
```

Comment: Error `Address already in use: bind` means that port is occupied. See my answer below and go through the steps. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Check if glassfish server is already running. This error occurs when an instance of the server is already running.

Run below command in `cmd`prompt : `netstat -ano`

This will list down the list of the processes currently running along with the port on which they are running. Search for the processes running on the port on which GlasshFish server is supposed to run.

If there is such a process running, we need to kill. We can do it in many ways.

We can use below command to kill the process based on the `PID(ProcessID)`. We will get the `ProcessId` from the last command we ran(`netstat -ano`). Let's say that the `PID` is `1234`. So the command will be

`Taskkill /PID 1234 /F`

Or we can do `Right click on window task bar -> 'Task Manager' -> Processes -> Search for the PID -> Select it and click on 'End Process' button at the bottom left corner-> Process is killed`

If we don't see a PID column in 'Processes' tab, click on `View` menu-item->`select columns` and `check-mark` PID entry.

Once the process is killed, try running the server again. This issue should not occur